# Replace sequence of identical values of length > 2

Tags: r, diff, run-length-encoding

I have a sensor that measures a variable and when there is no connection it returns always the last value seen instead of `NA`. So in my vector I would like to replace these identical values by an imptuted value (for example with `na.approx`).

```
set.seed(3)
vec <- round(runif(20)*10)
####  [1] 2 8 4 3 6 6 1 3 6 6 5 5 5 6 9 8 1 7 9 3
```

But I want only the sequences bigger than 2 (3 or more identical numbers) because 2 identical numbers can appear naturally. (in previous example the sequence to tag would be `5 5 5`)

I tried to do it with `diff` to tag my identical points (`c(0, diff(vec) == 0)`) but I don't know how to deal with the `length == 2` condition...

**EDIT**
my expected output could be like this:

```
####  [1] 2 8 4 3 6 6 1 3 6 6 5 NA NA 6 9 8 1 7 9 3
```

(The second identical value of a sequence of 3 or more is very probably a wrong value too)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `rle` to get the indices of the positions where `NA` should be assigned.

```
vec[with(data = rle(vec),
     expr = unlist(sapply(which(lengths > 2), function(i)
         (sum(lengths[1:i]) - (lengths[i] - 2)):sum(lengths[1:i]))))] = NA
vec
#[1]  2  8  4  3  6  6  1  3  6  6  5 NA NA  6  9  8  1  7  9  3
```

In function

```
foo = function(X, length){
   replace(x = X,
           list = with(data = rle(X),
                       expr = unlist(sapply(which(lengths > length), function(i)
                           (sum(lengths[1:i]) - (lengths[i] - length)):sum(lengths[1:i])))),
           values = NA)
}
foo(X = vec, length = 2)
#[1]  2  8  4  3  6  6  1  3  6  6  5 NA NA  6  9  8  1  7  9  3
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `lag` function

```
set.seed(3)
> vec <- round(runif(20)*10)
> 
> vec
 [1] 2 8 4 3 6 6 1 3 6 6 5 5 5 6 9 8 1 7 9 3
> 
> vec[vec == lag(vec) & vec == lag(vec,2)] <- NA
> 
> vec
 [1]  2  8  4  3  6  6  1  3  6  6  5  5 NA  6  9  8  1  7  9  3
>
```

Comment: cool. Is it possible to also replace NA starting at the second 5 not the third? (i updated my expected output)

Comment: yes that would be an extra step  `vec[which(is.na(vec)) - 1] <- NA`

Comment: ok, I could go with that, though it would mess up with "natural" NAs... initially present in the vector (it can happen). I would have to impute them first.

Comment: you can get around that by assigning the 3rd ones a specific value like -999 for example, then do the same foe the 2nd, and once you are done assign all of them NA, let me know if you need help with that.