# Identifying repeated sequences of numbers in time series

Tags: r, vector

I have a **long time series** where I need to identify and flag repeated sequences of values in R. Let's suppose I have the following vector:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,88,443,756,2,453,6,21,98,1,2,3,4,65)
```

Note that the sequence 1,2,3,4 is repeated at the beginning and almost at the end. I want to identify and flag **sequences of n** (n can be set) **repeated numbers** in a long time series. That's why I need a powerful method to do that.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: ...and what is the error? Where is your code to show what you tried?

Comment: I just want to know how to do it using R language

Comment: Perhaps you need `rle(c(TRUE, diff(a) == 1))`

Comment: that means reading tutorials.. SO is about fiing errors mainly. Try the statistics part of stackoverflow: right upper-corner next to the grey questionmark you find the list of exchange sites.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @JaumeRamon Does it work?

Comment: maybe this question can hep: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44574305/3871924

Comment: @PoGibas We are still testing it. I'll tell you. Thanks!!

Comment: @agenis I'm afraid to say that I don't want to find sequences of repeated numbers (2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), but repeated sequences of numbers (2,43,12,3,2,43,12,3). Please, note the subtile difference ;)

Comment: @JaumeRamon oh sorry. In that case you might want to ask to biostatisticians, they're experts in findings patterns in sequences of letters!

Comment: @JaumeRamon any updates on the question? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
identRptSeq <- function(x, N = 4) {
    # Create groups to split input vector in
    splits <- ceiling(seq_along(x) / N)
    # Use data.table shift to create overlapping windows
    foo <- lapply(data.table::shift(x, 0:(N-1), type = "lead"), function(x) {
                  res <- split(x, splits)
                  res[lengths(res) == N]})
    foo <- na.omit(t(as.data.frame(foo)))
    # Find duplicated windows
    foo[duplicated(foo), ]
}

# OPs input
a <- c(1,2,3,4,88,443,756,2,453,6,21,98,1,2,3,4,65)

# Duplicated sequence when N = 4
identRptSeq(a, 4)
[1] 1 2 3 4

# Duplicated sequences when N = 3
identRptSeq(a, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
X5      1    2    3
X5.1    2    3    4
```

PS, have in mind that it doesn't work when N = 1 (there are other methods in R for that)

Answer (score 1):

If you have exactly repeated patterns, this is just O(n). (just hash the sequences and look for collisions)

If you have almost repeated patterns (and are measuring the similarity by Euclidean Distance or correlation), then this is O(N^2), but the Matrix Profile algorithm(s) are very fast [a].

[a] http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/MatrixProfile.html

Comment: Am trying to find the c++ and data sets for snippet finder for converting to R, but [Snippet-Finder] (https://sites.google.com/site/snippetfinder/) its `404. That’s an error.`. Sorry to stalk you on SOF.